# JSON error with PHP/Jquery

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, json

I am not sure how I do this,
But baiscly what I want is to show an error message if the user does not have any friends. asking them to add some friends.

The PHP part of this code is returning [false] instead of the error message when it cant find any results in the first mysql.

Here is my jquery code

```
function fetchfriends(){
$.getJSON('sys/classes/core.php?task=fetchfriends&userid='+sessionparts[1], function(data) {



$.each(data, function(key, val) {
    if(val.error)
    {
    $('<div class="myfriendsbar">'+val.error+'</div>').appendTo('#mycontacts');
    return false;
    }
    else
    {

    $('<div class="myfriendsbar"><div id="friendsimage'+val.to_userid+'" style="width:32px; height:32px; float:left; margin:3px;"></div>'+val.firstname+' '+val.lastname+'<br/>'+val.username+'</div>').appendTo('#mycontacts');

    $('#friendsimage'+val.to_userid).css("background-image", "url(http://bonush.com/beta/sys/classes/photofetch.php?pic="+val.to_userid+":9177156176671)"); 

    }
  });


    });
```

and this is the PHP code

```
$number_check = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user_contact WHERE from_userid = '{$this->userid}'");

    if(!mysql_num_rows($number_check))
    {

            $arr = array('error' => "No Friends?<br/>Search above for New users or invite some friends.");
            print json_encode($arr);
    }
    else
    {
            $friendlook = mysql_query("%PRIVATECODE%");

            $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($friendlook);
            $rows[] = $row;
            print json_encode($rows);
    }
```

Comment: Bad formatting aside, you fail, in a fundamental sense, by not even stating what the error is.

Comment: THE Error is that they have no friends on our site. we want them to invite new users

Comment: How is having no friends an error? For me it's a life choice.

Comment: you just started something, got stuck and are requesting for someone to take a look at where you could be improving? can't help as i'm no php god, but it would help if you provide more info on what goes wrong, what works and where you run into problems

Comment: @Russel Well, if you can type that in a comment, surely you can type that in a question?

Comment: It's not a crime to have this kind of functionality in your code.  Certain parts of a website may not function without it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the way i see it you don't need the each on your return data if there is an error, first check for an error then if its not available run an each on it to print the friends...

```
function fetchfriends(){
$.getJSON('sys/classes/core.php?task=fetchfriends&userid='+sessionparts[1], function(data) {
    if(data.error)
    {
        // your data is an array of friends, unless you have an error, then it is no array, so no need for the each to print the error.
        $('<div class="myfriendsbar">'+data.error+'</div>').appendTo('#mycontacts');
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        //only when data.error does not exist it is filled as an array of friends you return i presume... 
        $.each(data, function(key, val) {
            $('<div class="myfriendsbar"><div id="friendsimage'+val.to_userid+'" style="width:32px; height:32px; float:left; margin:3px;"></div>'+val.firstname+' '+val.lastname+'<br/>'+val.username+'</div>').appendTo('#mycontacts');
            $('#friendsimage'+val.to_userid).css("background-image", "url(http://bonush.com/beta/sys/classes/photofetch.php?pic="+val.to_userid+":9177156176671)"); 
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In the "error" state, the JSON result will look like this:

```
{
  "error": "No friends? ... etc."
}
```

So when you do `$data.each` you'll get one iteration where `key` is `"error"` and `val` is `"No friends? ..."` etc. So, when you do `val.error` you're accessing the `error` property of a string, which doesn't exist.

Comment: @RussellHarrower Well, that's some useful information that should be in the question. The question is about the PHP, not the jQuery.

Comment: Sorry I only just found that out, after I wrote this questions.

Comment: The first thing to do when debugging JSON is to view the JSON - assuming you know what it will look like is always a problem.